# Rspec with special characters æ ø å

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, special-characters, rspec2

I am writing a Danish web app, and trying to verify email addresses. These can include the characters æ ø å among others. Here is my rspec code:

```
User.create(@attr.merge(:email => 'æøå@bætter.nåw.ørg'.to_s)).should be_valid
```

And my validation in User.rb:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, :presence => true, :format    => { :with => email_regex, :message => 'must be valid email' }, :uniqueness => true
```

This completely messes up rspec / autotest, which fails horribly with this stack trace:

> Exception encountered: # "æøå@bætter.nåw.ørg".to_s)... ...
>   ^> backtrace:
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in`
>   block in load'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:227:in
>   `load_dependency'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activesupport-3.0.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in`
>   load'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in
>   `block in load_spec_files'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in`
>   map'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in
>   `load_spec_files'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in`
>   run'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/monkey/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:5:in
>   `run_tests'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in`
>   block in run'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in
>   `block in initialize'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in`
>   fork'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in
>   `initialize'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in`
>   new'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/spork-0.9.0.rc3/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in`
>   run'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1558:in
>   `perform_without_block'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1518:in`
>   perform'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1592:in
>   `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in`
>   loop'
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1588:in
>   `block in main_loop' Unhandled exception: [#<ArgumentError: invalid
>   byte sequence in US-ASCII>]
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:842:in`
>   block in ': undefined method `backtrace' for
>   [#<ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII>]:Array
>   (NoMethodError)   from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in`
>   []'  from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in
>   `block in hook'   from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in`
>   each'    from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in
>   `any?'    from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:828:in`
>   hook'    from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:344:in
>   `rescue in run'   from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:320:in`
>   run'     from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/lib/autotest.rb:241:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ZenTest-4.5.0/bin/autotest:6:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/autotest:19:in `load'  from
>   /Users/houen/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/autotest:19:in`'  from -e:1:in `load'     from -e:1:in`'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Any suggestions as to how I solve this?

Comment: What's the part of the exception that is after the "Exception encountered" message and before the backtrace? You have only six dotted points there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe add this to the top of your test file (the one with special characters):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: @Houen, check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819637). Sounds like he had to use Notepad++ to change the character set, of the test file I would guess.