# page.should have_content - Special Characters causing error

Tags: rspec, syntax-error, rspec2

I am working on a basic Rspec test using Capybara that opens a webpage and checks that a string is contained within the home page. The tests require checking eaching of 8 different language sub domains on the sites and I have run into some problems with the special characters in the code.

The following code works:

```
it "should have an American Home page", :js => true do
  visit '/'
  page.should have_content('Workforce Management from InVision')
end

it "should have an English Home page", :js => true do
  visit '/uk/'
  page.should have_content('Workforce Management from InVision')
end
```

The following code **DOES NOT WORK**

```
it "should have a Spanish Home page at '/es/callcenter'", :js => true do
  visit '/es/'
  page.should have_content('Gestión de la plantilla con InVision')
end
```

I think that this is in relation to the ó in the word "Gestión". Any ideas how to stop this problem from occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `# encoding: UTF-8` on the first line of the spec file.

Comment: Hi there thanks for the reply unfortunately this didnt work, I am getting an "invalid multibye char (UTF-8) and syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end

Is there any way to include special character literals within the single brackets of the have_content method?

Comment: Solved this by changing the encoding to UTF-8 on notepad++ so an easy oversight to make

Answer (score 0):

For me  `# coding UTF-8` worked. You may also try that.